# Cannot create a channel in Hyperledger fabric docker setup?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I am very new to Hyperledger fabric stuff. I tried to build a network from scratch with docker. Everything work fine and network was up successfully. But when I was trying to create a channel it gave me this error.

```
2019-01-18 09:34:00.275 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> WARN 001 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-01-18 09:34:00.288 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> WARN 002 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-01-18 09:34:00.289 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> WARN 003 crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2019-01-18 09:34:00.291 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

This is my docker-compose-cli.yaml file.

```yaml
    version: "2"

    volumes:
      orderer.trafficfine.com:
      peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com:
      peer1.Mp.trafficfine.com:
      peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com:
      peer1.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com:
      peer0.AE.trafficfine.com:
      peer1.AE.trafficfine.com:

    networks:
      byfn:

    services:
      orderer.trafficfine.com:
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: orderer.trafficfine.com
        container_name: orderer.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer1.Mp.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer1Mp.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer1.Mp.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer1.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer1.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer1.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer0.AE.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer0.AE.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer0.AE.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      peer1.AE.trafficfine.com:
        container_name: peer1.AE.trafficfine.com
        extends:
          file: base/docker-compose-base.yaml
          service: peer1.AE.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn

      cli:
        container_name: cli
        image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        environment:
          - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
          - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
          #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
          - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
          - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
          - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.Msp.trafficfine.com:7051
          - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MpMSP
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Mp.trafficfine.com/peers/peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com/tls/server.crt
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Mp.trafficfine.com/peers/peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com/tls/server.key
          - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/peers/peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/tls/ca.crt
          - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        command: /bin/bash
        volumes:
          - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
          - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
          - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
          - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
          - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
        depends_on:
          - orderer.trafficfine.com
          - peer0.Mp.trafficfine.com
          - peer1.Mp.trafficfine.com
          - peer0.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
          - peer1.Policedepartment.trafficfine.com
          - peer0.AE.trafficfine.com
          - peer1.AE.trafficfine.com
        networks:
          - byfn
```

I looked for solutions on the Internet but I was unable to find a good solution for my problem. Can someone help me to solve my problem?. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@dwp, As per your volume mounts your source directory in your machine ("./crypto-config") was mounted to your container ("/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/")...

And the error says (let's take first one)
==> Intermediate certs folder not found at /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts

means there is no directory "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@Policedepartment.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts"..

So try to change the volume mount source and targets according to your crypto-config files..

To debug more into cli container use,

> > **docker exec -it cli bash**

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the new crypto material?
Try this:

> docker container exec -it cli bash

And search for the crypto directory, the error says that not found your crypto material files in your container, and you need it to make transactions over the network.

Comment: It is in the container